# Error in optim: function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters for Maximum likelihood estimation

Tags: r, optimization, mle

The code is this:

```
lm.loglik3 <-function(y, x, theta){N <-length(y)# theta contains our parameters to be estimated
beta0 <- theta[1]
beta1 <- theta[2]
sigma2 <- theta[3]# x contains our covariates
x1 <- x
logl <--N/2* log(2*pi*sigma2)-1/(2*sigma2)* sum((beta0+beta1*x1-y)^2)
return(-logl)}
# Starting Values
stval <-c(0, 0, 0)

# Optim
res3 <-optim(stval, lm.loglik3, y = df2$v64, x = df2$auth_val, hessian = TRUE)
```

I'm trying to do a maximum likelihood estimation using as parameters the degree of authoritarianism (numerical value are given) and the income. The database contains 6000 sample. Now the problem is that when i run the code it tells me "Error in optim: function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters". Some help?

Comment: df2$v64=income; df2$auth_val= authoritarianism

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the starting values of the parameters and the log likelihood

```
logl <--N/2* log(2*pi*sigma2)-1/(2*sigma2)* sum((beta0+beta1*x1-y)^2)
```

This breaks down if `sigma2` becomes zero for multiple reasons: you take the log zero (not nice) and divide by zero (not at all nice). In other words you need to ensure that your sigma2 is positive.

One simple (and classical) way of doing exactly that is to `exp()` the parameter input, so replace

```
sigma2 <- theta[3]# x contains our covariates
```

with

```
sigma2 <- exp(theta[3])# x contains our covariates
```

This allows the `optim()` function to use the full range of values but transforms the real line to the positive line so the likelihood makes sense. Just remember that the parameter estimate for `sigma2` returned by the `optim()` function will be the logged value.

---

**Update with full code and output**

The full code (with the change shown above) is

```
lm.loglik3 <-function(y, x, theta){
  N <-length(y)# theta contains our parameters to be estimated
  beta0 <- theta[1]
  beta1 <- theta[2]
  sigma2 <- exp(theta[3]) # x contains our covariates
  x1 <- x
  logl <- -N/2* log(2*pi*sigma2)-1/(2*sigma2)* sum((beta0+beta1*x1-y)^2)
  return(-logl)
}
```

When initialized with

```
stval <-c(0, 0, 0)

X <- c(8, 2, 4, 1, 1, 13, 2, 9, 2, 1, 7, 2, 1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 2, 2, 2, 
       3, 1, 14, 2, 1, 5, 2, 2, 4, 5)

Y <- c(18, 17, 13, 13, 20, 11, 11, 9, 8, 14, 8, 7, 15, 13, 12, 17, 
       10, 16, 14, 10, 13, 10, 12, 16, 18, 9, 9, 15, 13, 18)
```

we get

```
> res3
$par
[1] 13.4598331 -0.1292182  2.4549731

$value
[1] 79.3809

$counts
function gradient 
     178       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

$hessian
           [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
[1,] 2.57596526  9.8745335  0.00558974
[2,] 9.87453350 67.7478863  0.00621170
[3,] 0.00558974  0.0062117 14.98815391
```

Comment: Show us the data you are using so we can reproduce the error. What is x and y?

Comment: i've put the data

Comment: The code work exactly as desired with the data you provided. I've updated my answer and shown the full code and output

Comment: it works with the 30 samples. But i should do it on 6000 and it doesn't work giving me the same exact error. I could use only 30 samples maybe but than when I try to plot it it says to me: Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (6000): x, y

Comment: Now i've tried to put:   Y<-df2$auth_val[1:6000]
X<-df2$v64[1:6000]; finally doesn't give me the error with the MLE o_0, but now when I tried to plot it it says; Error in -ggplot(df2, aes(x = X, y = Y)) : 
 the argument is not valid for the operator..... GGplotcode: ggplot(df2, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", se = FALSE, size = 1, color = "purple") +
  xlab("Authoritarianism") + ylab("income") +
  ggtitle("Regression Plot") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

Comment: That is another question related to ggplot and problems surrounding that and has nothing to do with the MLE question you asked. You don't even have any ggplot code in your question that we could try to fix. If you have another question then ask it as a new question

Comment: Yes by the way i need to do it with 6000 samples, and it doesn't work giving me the same error, so the question remained

Comment: We cannot help you without you providing the data that gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
lm.loglik2 <- function(y, x, theta){
   N <- length(y)

   # theta contains our parameters to be estimated
   beta0 <- theta[1]
   beta1 <- theta[2]
   sigma2 <- exp(theta[3])


   logl <- - N / 2 * log(2 * pi * sigma2) - 
     1 / (2 * sigma2) * sum((beta0 + beta1 * x - y)^2)
   return(-logl)
 }

 # Starting Values
 stval <- c(0, 0, 1)
> 
> # Optim
> res3 <- optim(stval, 
               lm.loglik2,
               x=X
               y = Y,                
              hessian = TRUE)
Error in optim(stval, lm.loglik2, y = Y, x = X, hessian = TRUE) : 
  the function cannot be evaluated for its initial parameters
```

sigma2
coefficient: 0.46
standard error:0.07

X<- df2$v64

```
dput(df2$v64[1:30]) 
c(8, 2, 4, 1, 1, 13, 2, 9, 2, 1, 7, 2, 1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 1, 14, 2, 1, 5, 2, 2, 4, 5)
```

Y<- df2$auth_val

```
dput(df2$auth_val[1:30]) 
c(18, 17, 13, 13, 20, 11, 11, 9, 8, 14, 8, 7, 15, 13, 12, 17, 
10, 16, 14, 10, 13, 10, 12, 16, 18, 9, 9, 15, 13, 18)
```